# add space between ul and li tag css inline

Tags: html, css

I've the following code with nested list items as shown below:

```html
<ul style={{padding-top: '15px'}}>
                    <li style={{margin-left: '20px'}}>First Services</li>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get1</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get5</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    <li style={{margin-left: '20px'}}>Second Services</li>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get6</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get7</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get8</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get9</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get10</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get11</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get12</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                                <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get13 </a></li>
                            </ul>
                    <li style={{margin-left: '20px'}}>Workflows</li>
                        <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
                            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">Workflow for someone </a></li>
                        </ul>
            </ul>
```

**My Goal**:

I want some space between the following:

1)  `First Services` and `get1`

2) `get5` and `Second Services`

3) `Second Services` and `get6`

4) `get13` and `Workflows`

5)`Workflows` and `Workflow for someone`

How should I go about it? Is adding an empty paragraph tag `<p></p>` a good idea between each of the above 5 things?

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't have `<ul>` as a child of another `<ul>`. You can wrap these with `<li>` or `<div>`. On top of this, using HTML as spacers isn't the best method; I would add classnames or IDs to the things you want space around, and then write CSS that adds top or bottom margins

Comment: I don't think that's valid HTML. Your nested `<ul>`s should be inside a `<li>...</li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use classes for this. Right now, the simplest way is to wrap a `div` around your whole list, apply a class to it (in my example I used `parent_class`) and use this selector: `div.parent_class > ul >li` It only selects the `li` elements of the first level `ul`:

```css
div.parent_class > ul >li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_class">
  <ul style="padding-top:15px;">
    <li style="margin-left:20px">First Services</li>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get1</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get4</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <li style="margin-left:20px">Second Services</li>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get6</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get7</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get8</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get9</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get10</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get11</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get12</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get13 </a></li>
    </ul>
    <li style="margin-left:20px">Workflows</li>
    <ul style="margin-left:30px">
      <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">Workflow for someone </a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- if you mean horizontal space (white space), use: **&nbsp ;**
- if you mean vertical space, try: (CSS property) line-height, padding
  or margin.

you might want to remove this from being inline and use your linked stylesheet instead as it might cause issues with your styling.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .example-list {
        margin:0px;
    }

    .example-list > li {
        margin: 30px 0px;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="example-list">
        <li>First Services</li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get1</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul style={{margin-left: '30px'}}>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <li style={{margin-left: '20px'}}>Second Services</li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get6</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get7</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get8</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get9</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get10</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get11</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get12</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get13 </a></li>
        </ul>
        <li style={{margin-left: '20px'}}>Workflows</li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">Workflow for someone </a></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following (or something similar - keep in mind it's not good practice to have `<ul>` as a child of another `<ul>` - you can validate here: http://validator.w3.org/). Remove the inline styles, you'll deal with A LOT of headaches later if you write you CSS as you have. Set classnames for the bits you want extra space for (you can edit the `{{20px}}` below for how much space you want (or if you want left/right margins, you can edit the whole rule).

```
<style>
    .title {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .top-list {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .top-list .spacer-top {
        margin-top: {{20px}};
    }

    .top-list > li > ul {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
</style>

<ul class="top-list">
    <li class="title">First Services</li>
    <li class="spacer-top">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="title" class="spacer-top">Second Services</li>
    <li class="spacer-top">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get7</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get10</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get11</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">get13 </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="title spacer-top">Workflows</li>
    <li class="spacer-top">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://uri1" target="_blank">Workflow for someone </a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```